# get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); not working. How can I solve this?

Tags: post-thumbnails, homepage

I am using the following code to display the posts on my home page.

But I could not print **thumbnails** using `get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail');`

any help to solve this will be very much appreciated..

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();   
                $date = explode(",", get_the_time("F,j,Y", "", "", false));
                print(' 
                    <section class="large-4 columns">
                    <section class="main_post cbox1">
                    <section class="post_inner row collapse">');             
                    print('<div class="large-2 columns small-2">
                                <span class="date_format">
                                    <span class="date_num">' . $date[1] . '
                                    </span><br/><span class="date_month">' . substr($date[0], 0, 3) . '
                                    </span></span></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>');
                    print ('<div class="large-10 columns small-10">');
                            the_title('<a class="blogroll_title" href="' . get_permalink() . '"><h1 class="heading_blog">', '</h1></a>');
                    print ('</div>');                                   
                    print ('<!--end post_inner --></section>');
                    print ('<div class="row collapse post_content"><p>');
                        if (strlen(get_the_content()) > 100) {
                            $content = get_the_content();
                            echo str_replace('&nbsp;', '<br /><br />', substr($content, 0, 300)). "....";   
                            echo '</p><a href=" ' . get_permalink() . ' " class="read_more button button_top button_body_col11 button_radius">Read More</a>';
                            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); // post image thumbanails
                        }
                        else { the_content(); echo "</p>"; }
```

** if I use the `feature image` then it prints twice.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by " if I use the feature image then it prints twice."

Comment: there is a "featured image" tab at the right side of my "post" editor. If I click "set Featured image" and add an image, that image thumbnail is shown at the home page

Comment: try replacing `get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail')` to `get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail')`

Comment: @RiffazStarr This is how it is suppose to work, [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) gets the featured image. Check the codex for more details

Comment: @Shazzad thats not working for me.

Comment: @MarutiMohanty oowh... then How can I get a post image's thumbnails to my home page post summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of showing the thumbnail twice is because of your the_content(); which is defined in the content-page.php file that has the line the_post_thumbnail(); that will get the featured image.

so intead of using the the_content() just use the get_the_content() function to get only the content without the featured image.

Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that @yamu
It's solved now. I forget to remove the lines `if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
         the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        else{}`
I've ever added this to check it before. now the problem is these commands showing the thumbnail if the post image is featured. but I do not want to set the image to "FEATURED" every time. I just want to show the thumbnail if the post has any images.. any ideas?

Comment: Well that's not yet provided by wordpress to get any media in the content to show as thumbnail..